# How to uninstall Perl version 5.10.1 from Ubuntu 10.4 and install a single threaded version of Perl?

Tags: ubuntu, perl

I have to uninstall Perl version 5.10.1 from Ubuntu 10.4 and install a single threaded version of Perl. What commands should I run on terminal to do this? Or, is there another way to uninstall the version of Perl that came up with Ubuntu?

First, I tried to uninstall it from the Ubuntu software center but along with it, many other packages are getting removed and the system is crashing.

I also tried with `sudo apt-get remove perl`, but after that my system also crashed.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to leave the system `perl` alone, since, as you found out, it is often important to the running of the system.  Then you can compile and install from the latest source (pretty easy!), available at http://www.perl.org/, just being sure to set it to install to a different directory from the system's `perl`.  The help files that come with the download are pretty good at explaining everything that needs to be done.

Alternatively, if you just need Perl installed for a single user, you can use [Perlbrew](http://www.perlbrew.pl/) which will automatically download and install a variety of Perl versions in a user's home directory, though this is configurable:

> The default perlbrew root directory is ~/perl5/perlbrew, which can be changed by setting PERLBREW_ROOT

You can use the system's `cpan` to install Perlbrew itself, or use the commands given on the Perlbrew website.

EDIT:

ActiveState also offers binary downloads for Linux at [this site](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads), if you don't want to build from source.